# How can I allow uploading large files in OctoberCMS?

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-backend

Although I've set max file uploads and max post size to 2 GB in php.ini, I'm receiving this error when uploading media:

File is too big (541.02MiB). Max filesize: 256MiB.

How can I change max filesize?

This is the result of phpinfo():

```
upload_max_filesize 2000M
post_max_size 2000M
memory_limit = 512M
```

Comment: can you check this answer `https://octobercms.com/forum/post/media-error-after-uploading-a-file` - try to increase `memory_limit ` may be it can solve your issue.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not within the bounds of discussion as described in the help center.

Comment: it actually help, thanks Hardik!